# Can i control a modal in a controller with a invoking attribute in HTML on certain conditions(without any bootstrap services)using Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, modal-dialog

In my application i have modal to invoked on click of a button(ng-click) for certain conditions

my HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outlined" ng-click="vm.change()" data-modal-target="#add-save-all-alert-modal"></button>
```

my Controller

```
vm.change = function () {
    if(vm.modifiedBaseline &&  vm.modifiedBaselineToBeCommented){
    vm.modalFlag = true;
    } 
    else{
         st1;
         st2;
    }
   vm.modalFlag = false;
}
```

my Modal HTML

```
     <div data-modal id='add-save-all-alert-modal' class='bx--modal bx--
modal-tall' tabindex='-1'>
<div class='bx--modal-inner' style="width: 40%;margin-bottom: 400px;">
<div class="bx--modal-container">
  <button class='bx--modal__close' type='button' data-modal-close>
     <svg class='bx--modal__close--icon'>
    <use xlink:href='./././images/carbon-theme-ui/bluemix-icons.svg#close'></use>
  </svg>
</button>

<div class='bx--modal-content'>
  <p>Save Modified Baselines</p>
</div>

 <div class='bx--modal__buttons'>
  <div class='bx--modal__buttons-container'>
    <button class='bx--btn--secondary' type='button' data-modal-close>Cancel</button>
    <button class='bx--btn' type='button' data-modal-close>Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to control the open and close of a modal according to the if conditions in an controller.

How can control an data-modal-target attribute inside a controller for opening and closing of the modal?

Help me on this im stuck with this..Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: can you add your modal html here

Comment: i have added @user8175473

Comment: I guess there is a problem in html. close your container and its parent div with </div>

Comment: yeah added it doesn't seem to be a problem with my functionality to be implemented @user8175473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the data-modal-target from the html and use the click function to display or hide the modal

```
vm.change = function () {
    if(vm.modifiedBaseline &&  vm.modifiedBaselineToBeCommented){
     vm.modalFlag = true;
     $('#add-save-all-alert-modal').modal('show');
    } 
    else{
         st1;
         st2;
    }
   vm.modalFlag = false;
}
```

Refer [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) for opening a modal from the js instead of html unconditionally

Comment: I have tried this but on click the screen goes completely blank im not able to get the content of modal with the id @Manas Hemrajani

Comment: i have added a ng-include in  my HTML   <div ng-include="'app/........./add-save-all-alert-modal.html'"></div> to the path of the modal HTML

Comment: seems the issue is somewhere else then.. do you have a plunkr

Comment: This wont work because the classes in my modal HTML are of carbon design theme instead of bootstrap classes...may be so the screen is going blank ...this method works with all bootstrap classes i tried@Manas Hemrajani

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not recommended to use Jquery with angular.

In this case I suggest create a native HTML modal using bootstrap and control the display css property through a variable and ngClass

Else you can give a try to angular UI

[Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/)